# SwiftMailerBundle addPart not found

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-2.3

Looking in the documentation swiftmailer, in order to include both the message format to text in HTML format you need to use the method `addPart`: [swiftmailer doc](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#quick-reference-for-creating-a-message)

```
// Give it a body
->setBody('Here is the message itself')

// And optionally an alternative body
->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')
```

But to my surprise this method is not found by Symfony2 and I do not know how to solve my problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use and for me this is works:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($subject)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->setTo($emailAddress)
                ->setBody(
                    $this->templating->render(
                        $template.'.txt.twig',
                        $parameterArray
                    )
                )
                ->addPart(
                    $this->templating->render(
                        $template.'.html.twig',
                        $parameterArray
                    ),'text/html'
                );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are receiving this `Method 'addpart' not found in \Swift_Mime_MimePart` message in an IDE, in my case PHP Storm, then I found that I had to re-declare the `$message` variable as a `\Swift_Message` object.

The IDE is using the return value type of the parent class `Swift_Mime_MimePart` as it is using a parent method, and so it does not accept a child method in the child class `Swift_Message`.

Not very tidy, as it breaks the method chaining, but it does resolve the analysis errors:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
    ->setFrom('send@example.com')
    ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
            'Emails/registration.html.twig',
            array('name' => $name)
        ),
        'text/html'
    )
;
/* @var \Swift_Message $message */
$message
    ->addPart(
        $this->renderView(
            'Emails/registration.txt.twig',
            array('name' => $name)
        ),
        'text/plain'
    )
;
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```